# Корректно ли сказать "по приезду"?

Tags: падежи

> По своем приезде я закатил пирушку. (когда/по чем?  = по приездЕ)

> По этому событию я закатил пирушку. (по какому поводу? = по случаЮ)

> По приезду я закатил пирушку. (по какому поводу? = по своему приездУ)

Корректно ли последнее предложение?

Comment: Создаётся впечатление, что второе предложение Вы считаете корректным. *По празднику (=по какому поводу?) прошёл парад* — звучит дико. (Не путать с "ударим автопробегом по бездорожью и разгильдяйству" — здесь всё корректно, но автопробег здесь совсем не "по поводу".)

Comment: По этой причине прошел парад/По этому случаю прошел парад/По этому поводу прошел парад. -- норма.
По этому событию прошел парад. --на мой взгляд тоже норма ведь здесь мы используем слово "событие" в качестве синонима слова "случай".
Но вы правы, с произвольными существительными так не получается. Следовательно и третье предложение заведомо неверное. Хотя попытка оправдать повсеместное "по приезду" была неплохая. Думаю что ваш коммент надо преобразовать в ответ, он закрывает вопрос.

Comment: *По этому событию прошел парад.* — это не норма. Для полного понимания Вам остаётся обратить внимание, что *по случаю*, *по причине*, *по поводу* в подобных выражениях употребляются в значении предлогов (см. Кузнецова).

Comment: А.. тогда просто ждем когда "по приезду" перейдет в разряд предлогов :) Хотя это все равно не поможет ибо "по причине я закатил пирушку" некорректное предложение. Однако "по этому событию я закатил пирушку" стало бы корректным

Answer (score 1):

По приезду (= по какому случаю) я закатил пирушку? Нет, так не говорят. Надо сказать: ***По случаю приезда я закатил пирушку.***

Не согласны? Тогда приведите пример из художественной литературы с подобным сочетанием (по приезду в значении по случаю приезда).

Вот пример Д.п.: Все расходы **по приезду** приму на себя. (1910.05.17) // «Петербургская газета», 1910]

**Примечание**

Можно обратить внимание на следующее. Судя по Нацкорпусу, раньше использовали форму ***по приезду*** и в значении "после приезда", например: Всё сие узнал Петр на третий день **по приезду** в Торунь от генерал-майора Гольца, присланного королем Августом. [А. С. Пушкин. История Петра: Подготовительные тексты (1835-1836)]

Интересно, когда и почему изменилась норма. Может быть, вариант "по приезде" казался неблагозвучным?

Comment: Интересно. Сам Пушкин не отказал себе в удовольствии повторить за народом "по приезду". С чего бы это.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, корректно только "по приезде".

Comment: Не согласен. Я ведь ясно обосновал корректность "По приезду" в смысле "По этому случаю"